# Easy and practical approach to change/re-write URLs in Yii

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting

I've read pretty much everything about Yii, such as Ullmans book, the guide, on several forums and of course exploring the framework files. As I'm learning to program at the time I do however rely on pratical examples to connect with the theory and I can't seem to find any useful on the Yii URL part (almost all examples is about removing index.php or shorten the URL).

So I'm kindly asking anyone to give me a practical example on how to change e.g.

http://www.domain.com/Yii/index.php/programsgames/739

Into

http://subdomain.domain.com/?title-of-item/title-of-category/title-of-main-category/739

And perhaps discuss if it's best to change in CUrlManager.php or in .htaccess?

I could imagine that a lot that could benifit from this example as it includes a subdomain, an URL change and additions to in as well. Hope that I'm not way off!

Comment: Note that you wouldn't ever want to edit CUrlManager or any other core Yii component directly, as it will make upgrading Yii painful in the future. Instead, you would use a subclass of the appropriate class and swap it in in your config file.

Comment: I see. Thanks Acorncom. But can anyone provide a pratical example of the URL transformation above? Also thanks user1986938 but that was not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php you should add  'showScriptName'=>false, in urlmanager array in your config file.

For formating path maybe something like this could be used.

```
'http://<subdomain:\w+>.domain.com/<item-title:\w+>/<item-category:\w+>/<main-category:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'yourcontroller/youraction'
```